# image slide not working properly in Java script

Tags: slideshow

i am new here and trying add a image slider in my webpage. but i have tried several codes, the problem is my IE just showing only first image. then there is no image. MY IE is IE 11 and i am using netbeans8.0.2 and xampp.

what is the problem of not showing all the images in the slide?

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>image slider!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var im1 = new Im();
            im1.src = "1.jpg";
        var im2 = new Im();
            im2.src = "2.jpg";
        var im3 = new Im();
            im3.src = "3.jpg";
        var im4 = new Im();
            im.src = "4.jpg";
        var im5 = new Im();
            im5.src = "5.jpg";
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <img src="slides/1.jpg" name="slider1" width=800 height=380 />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var i=1;
        function slidimage()
        {
            document.images.slider1.src = eval("im"+i+".src");
            if (i<5)
            {
                i++;
             }     
            else
        {
                i=1;
                }
            setTimeout("slidimage()",2000);
        }
        slidimage();
        </script>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

i have got this code from another post in stackoverflow by amin

sorry for the copy.